# Opening a new window in WPF

Tags: wpf, browser, window

I want to open a new browser window with a specific url (say http://google.com")  when I click a button in my wpf application. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Or, if you want to open it in the same application :

```
NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
window.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
window.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a LinkLabel like [this](http://www.blagoev.com/Blog/post/Building-a-WPF-LinkLabel-control.aspx).